# The odd power of copositive matrix

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, matrices

If $A$ is copositive, what about $A^3$? Is it also copositive? More generally,
my question is whether the odd power of a copositive matrix is still copositive.

Any reference is appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A counter-example is given by
$$\pmatrix{.6,0,0,.6,1}\pmatrix{
1 & -1 & 1 & 1 & -1 \\\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & 1 \\\
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\\
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1} ^3 \pmatrix{.6 \\\ 0 \\\ 0\\\ .6 \\ 1}=-0.44.$$

while the matrix in the centre is actually copositive. It is easy to check that there are no counter-examples for $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: ah! you typed in the answer while I was typesetting it. Same matrix ;-)

Answer (score 11):

My preliminary experiments show that the answer is *no*. Here is why.

In the paper [Constructing copositive matrices from interior matrices](http://www.math.technion.ac.il/iic/ela/ela-articles/articles/vol17_pp09-20.pdf), the following matrix (from Horn's quadratic form) is mentioned to be copositive:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 &   -1 &    1  &   1 &  -1\\\\
 -1 &   1 &   -1  &   1 &   1\\\\
 1  &  -1 &    1  &  -1 &   1\\\\
 1  &   1 &   -1  &   1 &  -1\\\\
 -1 &   1 &    1  &  -1 &   1\\\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now plug this matrix into Matlab, and search to see if $x^TA^3x < 0$ occurs for a nonnegative $x$. Here is one particular value:

$$x = \begin{pmatrix}
4\\\\
6\\\\
3\\\\
0\\\\
0\\\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
because with this choice of $x$, we obtain $x^TA^3x = -11$

Comment: We both gave the same example, though I've seen $A$ in another context, it is given as a counter-example to "every copositive matrix is the sum of a positive semidefinite and nonnegative matrix".

Comment: @Gjergji: Nice! In the abovecited paper too, they mention that this matrix is an example of an "exceptional" copositive matrix (i.e., a copos matrix that is not of the semidef + nonneg form)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to tick both answers, but the system don't allow.... I know you don't mind about this.  

Comment: You are welcome; and of course, no problems!